# How to create seed models in different schemas when having multiple seed paths

Tags: unit-testing, dbt

I am trying to set up unit testing in my dbt project using the dbt package [dbt_datamocktool](https://hub.getdbt.com/mjirv/dbt_datamocktool/latest/). My test data lies in the path `tests/test_data/*`.

I have configured multiple seed paths in my `project.yml` file as follows:

```
seed-paths: [ "seeds", "tests/test_data" ]
```

So my project looks something like this:

```
├── seeds
│   ├── data.csv
├── tests
│   ├── test_data
│   │   ├── test_data.csv
```

I want to separate both seed directories to have all my testing resources in one place.

With my test-data directory in place, I also want to create this data within a specific database schema (e.g. `<schema-name>_test_data`).

In the `project.yml` file it is possible to configure specific schemas for different directories:

```
seeds:
  project_name:
    +schema: seeds
    sub-directory:
      +schema: sub_directory
```

But somehow, I am not able to add my specific test-data directory to this. At least I did not find any information on how to this.

Maybe someone can help me with this :)

Thanks!

I tried adding additional configuration to the seeds section in my `project.yml` file, but this either resulted in a warning like `Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.` or nothing happened at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that you have specified a *path* in `seed-paths` which, despite it's name, [expects a list of *directories*](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/seed-paths#definition).

Change the seed paths list to

```
seed-paths: [ "seeds", "tests" ]
```

and then your dbt_project.yml to

```
seeds:
  project_name:
    +schema: seeds
    test_data:
      +schema: some_other_schema
```

The above config makes "seeds" the default schema for seed files but overrides it for files in tests\test_data to "some_other_schema".